# Python 3 discord bot string to byte conversion

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

So I'm trying to create a Discord bot in Python 3.5 that has the ability to disassemble bytes to Inteli386 instructions, I'm using the discord.py library, and capstone's python binding.

Basically I got all of that working but I've ran into one problem, I can't store it as a byte because it's returned as a string from discord, and idk how to "convert" or store it as a byte without the value staying the same.

So for example if a user typed in \xC3 it'd be picked up as a string type, and for it to go through capstone's disasm function I need to change the data type \xC3 is being stored as as a byte.

Then feed the disasm function \xC3 as a byte.

I've looked this up but all I can find is string.encode, and stuff like that which doesn't feed the disassembler library the correct byte and instead converts the actual string to some other byte and has a completely different output then "ret".

tl;dr

I need to know how to convert a value stored as a string in python 3 to be stored as a byte "\xC3" for example

Comment: It's a bit of a kludge, but you can do `ast.literal_eval("b'{}'".format(s))`, where `s` is the string you get from discord.  [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) is like `eval`, but safer.